# Pagination в PDO скрытие страниц

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

Сделал Pagination в PDO. Как теперь сделать, что бы страницы при большем количестве страниц скрывались за ... (тремя точками). 
Например 1 ... 13 14 **15** 16 17 ... 50. У меня сейчас идут в ряд от 1 до 50.

```
 <?php
    include_once("db.php");

    function getAllArticles($start, $limit) {
        $db = new Database;
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit);
        $db = null;
        return $result;
    }

    function countArticles() {
        $db = new Database();
        $dbh = $db->getDb();
        $result = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `news`");
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
        $dbh = null;
        return $row[0];
    }

    function makeStatement ( $sql, $data = null ){
        $db = new Database();
        $dbh = $db->getDb();
        $statement = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
        try {
            $statement->execute( $data );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $exceptionMessage = "<p>You tried to run this sql: $sql <p>
                    <p>Exception: $e</p>";
            trigger_error($exceptionMessage);
        }       
        $dbh = null;
        return $statement;
    }   

    function getStart($page, $limit) {
        return $limit * ($page - 1);
    }

    function pagination($page, $limit) {
        // общее кол-во строк в БД
        $count_articles = countArticles();
        // общее количество стр.
        $count_pages = ceil($count_articles / $limit);
        if ($page > $count_pages) $page = $count_pages;
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        if ($prev < 1) $prev = 1;
        if ($next > $count_pages) $next = $count_pages;
        $pagination = "";
        if ($count_pages > 1) {
            // pagination
            if ($page == 1) {
                $pagination .= "<span>1Первая </span>";
                $pagination .= "<span>1Предыдущая </span>";
            }
            else {
                $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'>2Первая </a>";
                if ($prev == 1) $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'>2Предыдущая </a>";
                else $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$prev."'>21Предыдущая </a>";
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count_pages; $i++) {
                if ($i == $page) $pagination .= "<span> ".$i." </span>";
                elseif ($i == 1) $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'> ".$i." </a>";
                else $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i." </a>";
            }
            if ($page == $count_pages) {
                $pagination .= "<span> 3Следующая</span>";
                $pagination .= "<span> 3Последняя</span>";
            }
            else {
                $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$next."'> 4Следующая</a>";
                $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$count_pages."'> 4Последняя</a>";
            }
        }
        return $pagination;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб

```
var_dump(buildPageList(27, 30));

function buildPageList($current, $count, $offest = 2) {
    $first = $current - $offest;
    $last = $current + $offest;
    if ($first < 1) {
        $first = 1;
    }
    if ($last > $count) {
        $last = $count;
    }
    $pages = [];
    if ($first > $offest - 1) {
        $pages[] = 1;
    }
    if ($first > $offest) {
        $pages[] = "...";
    }
    for ($i = $first; $i < $last + 1; $i++) {
        $pages[] = $i;
    }
    if ($last < $count - $offest + 1) {
        $pages[] = "...";
    }
    if ($last < $count) {
        $pages[] = $count;
    }

    return $pages;
}
```

Comment: Как мне это реализовать в моем коде, не много, не понятно.

Comment: Можешь помочь реализовать это на моем коде? Спасибо